# How split this into new Date

Tags: javascript, regex

I am grabbing a node from XML that returns the date like this :

```
2011-06-24T03:00:00
```

If I try to run new Date I am getting a `NaN` error.

```
 var shippedDate = new Date($j(this).find("Shipment").find("Date").text())

 $j("#result").append(shippedDate.getDate() + "/" + shippedDate.getMonth() + "/" + shippedDate.getFullYear() );
```

I am thinking I need to use a regular expression to grab everything before the T and drop the rest then it will work ?

Can someone please show me what that regex would look like or if there is another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there might be an issue with how you are calling `$j(this)` because when I strip it all out, it works:

```
var shippedDate = new Date("2011-06-24T03:00:00");

 $("#result").append(shippedDate.getDate() + "/" + shippedDate.getMonth() + "/" + shippedDate.getFullYear() );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Ry9u8/

Comment: ahh story of my week.  Thanks for giving me the inspiration to try again.. now it works and I have no idea why :-/  Time for the weekend ?

Answer (score 3):

It works just fine for me

```
var somedate = new Date('2011-06-24T03:00:00');

// Fri Jun 24 2011 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8Xwbj/2/

Are you sure the `$j(this).find("Shipment").find("Date").text()` returns what you expect it to ?

Comment: we are thinking the same thing

Comment: @Jason, indeed.. i also tried to edit my answer, and edited yours by mistake :p .. (*rolled it back*)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Date.parse()` to get the date from an string :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

`"2011-06-24T03:00:00".match(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The dateString must follow RFC 1123 timestamps or since JavaScript 1.8.5 [subset of ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date strings so it could be picked up by the `parse` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

From [Mozilla JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> new Date(milliseconds)
> new Date(dateString)
>
> *dateString*
> String value representing a date. The
> string should be in a format
> recognized by the parse method
> (IETF-compliant RFC 1123 timestamps).
>
> *milliseconds*
> Integer value representing the number
> of milliseconds since 1 January 1970
> 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `indexOf` method of javascript's String object in combination with the `substr` method, i.e.:

```
$string.substr(0, $string.indexOf('T'));
```

I'm more a java/perl coder than a javascript coder, so my syntax might be slightly off, but I hope you get the idea.